# Linux Compton: How to Remove Window Shadow for Undecorated JFrame

Tags: java, linux, jframe, shadow

I have created an undecorated per-pixel-translucency JFrame in Java. The size of the frame (in the screeny below) is 512x512. I've only added 3 images to it so far. My problem is that the window shadow created by Compton pretty much ruins the effect of the per-pixel-translucency. I've been trying to find out how to disable the window shadow for JFrames but I cannot find anything regarding Compton.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there perhaps a way to run a command to disable Compton for a particular process via command line? In that case I could use Runtime.exec().

**What I've tried:**

- `setUndecorated(true);`
- `getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.shadow", Boolean.FALSE);`
- `setType(Type.UTILITY);`
- `setType(Type.POPUP);`

*Note: I still want Compton to be active, just not for this particular JFrame.*

Comment: Something like this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compton#Disable_conky_shadowing

Comment: Thanks, that guided me into the right direction. :D

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not a solution for all applications with transparent windows, it works for me since I only want this single application to not use Compton shadows.

Solution:

1. Create a Compton config file.
2. Add `shadow-exclude = [ "name = 'WindowTitle'" ];` where `WindowTitle` is the title of the window.
3. Execute `pkill compton` in terminal.
4. Start Compton and make sure it is linked to the config file with the `--config` parameter.

That's it.